# What is the order of function arguments evaluation and structs initialization in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is the order of function argument evaluation defined in Rust?

```rust
fn f(a: u64, b: u64, c: u64) {}
fn g() -> u64 { 0 }
fn h() -> u64 { 1 }
fn i() -> u64 { 2 }

fn main() {
    f(g(), h(), i());
}
```

Also, I am worried about the initialization order of structs:

```rust
fn f() {}
fn g() {}

A {
    a: f(),
    b: g(),
}
```

Is the order guaranteed to be `a` and then `b`?

For my particular use case, I am going to initialize a struct within a `diesel` transaction like that:

```rust
db_connection.transaction(||
    Ok(CompanyAndUser {
        company: companies::register_company(...)?, // performs diesel insert
        user: users::register_user(...)?, // performs diesel insert
    })
);
```

Obviously, I want these two diesel calls within a transaction to be ordered.
I have not found any information about this, unfortunately. Also, I've found some more or less relevant info, but it was quite old.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The order used to be unspecified, but it's now [left-to-right](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order-of-operands):

> Many expressions contain sub-expressions, called the operands of the expression.

and:

> The operands of these expressions are evaluated prior to applying the effects of the expression. Expressions taking multiple operands are evaluated left to right as written in the source code.

Comment: There's no need for this. Struct fields are evaluated in the order you write them. See [Niko's](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/rust-expression-order-of-evaluation/2605/30) answer.

Comment: If you have this `struct A { a: u8, b: u8 }` structure and you write `A { a: a(), b: b() }` then the order is `a()` and then `b()`. If you write `A { b: b(), a: a() }` then the order is `b()` and then `a()`.

Comment: @zrzka I have updated about the struct initialization, but I can add the Niko's answer, if you don't have concern about me stealing your comment :P

Comment: Stealing here? :) Community effort, I don't own anything, feel free :)

Comment: This answer is outdated. The order is documented and guaranteed to be left-to-right now: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order-of-operands. _"Expressions taking multiple operands are evaluated left to right as written in the source code."_